# Normalize filenames: remove space, replace international characters

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking for a solution to batch normalize filenames with bash:

- Replace space with "_"
- Replace international characters  "`ť,ž,ý,á,í,é,ő,ú,ű,ó,ü,ö...`" with english equivalent "`t,z,y,a,i,e,o,u,u,o,u,o...`"

Comment: My first thought is to use `tr`: `tr " ťžýáíéőúűóüö..." "_tzyaieouuouo..."`

Comment: @mbratch, not sure if this applies to the general case. Listing *all* possible transliterations You could find in UTF-8 set doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: @Kamiccolo I would agree, but the OP didn't say how big the character set is, so I tossed that option out there as a comment. If all possibilities really are required, then there's work to set up the manual translation table, then write a script to translate.

Comment: What character set are you using? In Unicode, many characters don't have obvious English equivalents.

Comment: The OP seems to be targeting Hungarian (at least, I know of no other languages that use `ű`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command line tool `iconv` for this purpose. It also supports transliteration. Here is a simple example:

```
echo "Viele Grüße" |
iconv --to-code ASCII//TRANSLIT
```

The output is: `Viele Grusse`.

You can use it to *normalize* pathnames stored in variables as follows:

```
pathname="$( iconv --to-code ASCII//TRANSLIT <<< "${pathname// /_}" )"
```